# Pandas filter original dataframe instead of taking a view

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to keep only rows where column is between 10 and 100

I found this

```py
df = df.loc[df['col'].between(10, 100)]
```

But now

```py
df['size'] = df['other_col'].aggregate(my_func)
```

Shows this warning

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
```

I guess that `df.loc` returns a slice of the original dataframe instead of a new dataframe.

How do I keep only rows I want in a dataframe?

I also learnt about

```py
df.drop(..., inplace=True)
```

But find the semantics unpleasant, I have to invert my keep condition which I don't want to have to do.

Comment: You can ignore this warning.

Comment: @MykolaZotko because the warning uses the phrasing "**_trying_** to be set", it sounds like this assignment is either not going to be successful, or not guaranteed to be successful?

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be successful, very similar to [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this should solve it

```py
df = df.loc[df['col'].between(10, 100)].copy()
```

Without expensively copying the entire DataFrame, this might work:

```py
df.drop(df.index[df['col'].between(10, 100)].tolist(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: Isn't there a way without expensively copying the entire dataframe?

Comment: @minseong Maybe this works: `df.drop(df.index[df['col'].between(10, 100)].tolist(), inplace=True)`. Don't know for sure since I can't test it as you did not provide any example data.

Comment: It should go the other way: `df = df.loc[].copy()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I think he does not want to make a copy at all. But what you suggest is an improvement.